# Data validation when using rhandstable in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following Shiny application to produce an editable table.

```
library(shiny)

UI <- fluidPage(
  rHandsontableOutput('contents')
)
Server <- function(input, output) {

  list1 <- c("Bank", "Bank")
  list2 <- c("NA","NA")
  df <- data.frame(list1, list2)

  output$contents <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(df)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = UI, server = Server)
```

It works fine. However, I would like to include a dropdown list with which I can replace the values. So let's says I have a vector like this:

```
categories <- c("expenses", "income")
```

How can include this so that when I click on a cell in the second column I get the opportunity to choose between expenses and income?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done if you define `df` as `df <- data.frame(list1, list2)`

and

```
output$contents <- renderRHandsontable({
  rhandsontable(df) %>% hot_col(col = 'list2', type = "dropdown", source = list2)

})
```

However, this seems to work only if the length of the vector list2 is greater than 3.